# NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for {:factory=>:user}:Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I get an error when I call create on the character factory

```
    factory :user do |f|
        f.sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
        f.password "password"       
  end

    factory :character do |f|
        f.name "testcharone"
        f.race "human"
    after(:create) { |character| character.init("fighter")}
    association factory: :user
  end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `to_sym' for {:factory=>:user}:Hash
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

This test took 16 minutes to complete, while the others, which are similiar took between 5-10 minutes

```
describe Character do   
    let(:character) { FactoryGirl.create :character}

  describe "#add_units" do  
        context "when unit doesnt exist beforehand" do          
        it "it create a new member" do
            expect(character.owns.count).to eq(0)
            character.add_units("character", "Archer" => 1)
            expect(character.owns.count).to eq(1)
            expect(character.owns.first.amount).to eq(1)
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 6):

In `factory :character`,

Replace

```
 association factory: :user
```

With

```
 association :user
```

You have to pass only the factory name i.e., `:user` in this case and not a hash `factory: :user`

Comment: ah that got rid of the error, but now my rspec takes 15 minutes to complete a very simple test

Comment: it should be `f.association :user` not not `association :user`

Comment: @RajarshiDas Its not mandatory. BUT for consistency purpose yes.

Comment: @manis It depends on the example's you are running. test a single example and see how much time it takes. For example : `rspec spec/path/to/some_spec.rb -e "My Example"` where you have an example `it "My Example"`.

Answer (score 1):

You facotry should be as  like below

Hope you should ahave a factory for `user` as well

```
factory :character do |f|
   f.name "testcharone"
   f.race "human"
   f.association :author, factory: :user
   after(:create) { |character| character.init("fighter")}
end
```

or

```
 factory :character do 
   name "testcharone"
   race "human"
   association :user
   after(:create) { |character| character.init("fighter")}
end
```